# ScrollView content inside Fragment is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know StackOverflow already has some posts regarding this problem and I already followed the solutions provided on them, but still can't scroll the content inside a ScrollView.

I have the following structure:

```
MainActivity
|_ LinearLayout (Vertical)
    |_ FragmentA
    |_ FragmentB


FragmentA
|_ RelativeLayout
    |_ ScrollView
         |_ LinearLayout (Horizontal)
```

Here is the code of FragmentA:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="br.com.hqcomicsonline.app.ui.fragments.FilterFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `match_parent` for both `width` and `height` for the inner `Linearlayout` inside the `ScrollView`. That means it never grows larger than its parent - therrefore the `ScrollView` never needs to become scrollable.

It only becomes scrollable when you add multiple `Views` which in total exceed the sizes of the screen/available space for the `ScrollView`.

**EDIT:**

Also since your `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`, you should use a `HorizontalScrollView` instead of a simple `ScrollView`.

Comment: I changed the inner `LinearLayout` to use `wrap_content` for both `width` and `height` but still doesn't work. One thing I forgot to mention is that `LinearLayout` content is created in runtime (in a loop inside `onCreateView`).

Comment: I was so sure that the problem was related to the `Fragment` and didn't realize that I should be using `HorizontalScrollView`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `ScrollView` with a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`